# How to create simple C# full-duplex TCP/IP stream socket connection?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, duplex

### How to create simple C# full-duplex TCP/IP stream socket connection?

What do I need? I need -

- Open Source Libs
- Tutorials
- Blog posts/Articles

---

Answer (score 3):

```
new NetworkStream(socket)
```